# How to strip comments from Webpack's bundle without formatting the code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How do I tell Webpack to remove only comments, but otherwise leave the output bundle untouched? The solution needs to support source maps.

`UglifyWebpackPlugin` and `TerserWebpackPlugin` are not good options at all: they both are doing too much, and they crash my desktop with OOM every time. I have a very large output file, and I just want to strip comments and nothing more. These minifiers seem to be trying to do too much with the large output, but I don't need all of whatever they are doing.

I'm wondering if there's another way to have Webpack strip comments from the output bundle, without crashing.

Comment: The UglifyjsWebpackPlugin uses UglifyJS2, take a look at what options might be helpful - [command-line-options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#command-line-options)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. Thanks but as the question says, I don't want to use a tool with full-out minification features just to strip comments. Even Terser, the newer (supposedly faster) successor to Uglify, crashes with out-of-memory on my huge output bundle, because probably it is running the code through much of the same machinery that it does for minification despite that all I want is to strip comments (that's my guess, at least). One would think there's a simple way to tell Webpack to do nothing but strip comments after a build.

Comment: Have you ever thought about deleting comments after building build using nodejs without a webpack? [strip-comments](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/strip-comments)

Comment: @GrzegorzT.Yeah I thought about that, then I had to think about how to make my own source maps which was no an appealing thought. Ideally the solution would be inside Webpack, and would integrate with all of its features including source maps. Honestly saying though, I would like to eliminate all tooling and use native ES Modules in modern browsers. But even if browsers support it, some libraries don't support it yet (they're distributed as CommonJS).